# Regex Split String on Delimiter

Tags: regex

My data is underscore-delimited like this for example:

**A_B_C_D_E**

Regex **1** I need to match: **A__C_D_E**

Regex **2** I need to match: **A_B__D_E**

Regex **3** I need to match: **A_B_C__E**

A little background on this.  I'll be replacing the regex matches with empty.string thus leaving me with the value of each column.  Example, regex 1 would leave me with the value B when the match is replaced by empty.string.  IMPORTANT:  ABCDE are all dyanmic data...they are not literally ABCDE.  The underscore delimiter is literal.  The number of "columns" delimited by this underscore is constant.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean to select with the regex?

Comment: Why don't you just split the data by underscores? Regex seems unnecessary here.

Comment: What programming language? In general, a single regex can't match the left and right halves of something.

Comment: @PedrovonHertwig I need multiple regex.  Each regex would exclude a "column".  In the example above regex1 would match everything except B. Regex 2 would match everything except C.  Regex 3 would match everything except D.  Remembering that BCD are not litteral but dynamic data.

Comment: @NetMage i'm using an online tool that excepts a regex as a means of matching data you want to remove.  it removes the data by replacing the regex match with string.empty.  To answer your question, I don't know what programming language they're using on the backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For case 1:**

Search using:

```
^([^_]*_)[^_]*
```

And replace by:

```
$1
```

[RegEx Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/YuQnhU/1)

---

**For case 2:**

Search using:

```
^((?:[^_]*_){2})[^_]*
```

And replace by:

```
$1
```

[RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/YuQnhU/2)

---

**For case 3:**

Search using:

```
^((?:[^_]*_){3})[^_]*
```

And replace by:

```
$1
```

[RegEx Demo 3](https://regex101.com/r/YuQnhU/3)