# Java regex pattern to split String based on delimiter string "|-|"

Tags: java, arrays, regex, split

I have a java string delimited by **|-|** like below.

Can't find |-| deliter based split any where else this is unique.

```
String agent = "iOS|-|iPhone|-|18.2.3|-|kuoipo-kjpopoo-kijhloii-kllkijii";
```

What is the correct regex to split the contents in string Array like below.

```
String[] dataarray;
dataarray[0]="iOS";
dataarray[1]="iPhone";
dataarray[2]="18.2.3";
dataarray[3]="kuoipo-kjpopoo-kijhloii-kllkijii";
```

Already tried:

```
agent.split("\\|-\\|");
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex Split String on Delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44316861/regex-split-string-on-delimiter)

Comment: Show us what you tried.

Comment: see your last tag

Comment: Tried agent.split("\\|-\\|");

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split a string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java)

Comment: @RajeshBabu In what way did that fail to do what you wanted? I ask, because it is the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Won't work

```
agent.split("|-|")
```

Do

```
agent.split("\\|-\\|")
```

Comment: That is what OP tried (see [comment to question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51844997/java-regex-pattern-to-split-string-based-on-delimiter-string#comment90643494_51844997)).